# Bourne Script: Redirect success messages but NOT error messages

Tags: bash, scripting, stdout, shell

This command:

```
keytool -import -file "$serverPath/$serverCer" -alias "$clientTrustedCerAlias" -keystore "$clientPath/$clientKeystore" -storepass "$serverPassword" -noprompt
```

Will when it runs successfully outputs: `Certificate was added to keystore`

I tried redirecting the stdard out with:

```
keytool ... > /dev/null
```

But it is still printing.

It appears that the message is being output into standard error.  Since when I do this it is not displayed:

```
keytool ... > /dev/null 2>&1
```

However this is not what I am wanting to do.  I would like error messages to be output normally but I do not want "success" messages to be output to the command line.  Any ideas?  Whatever happened to unix convention: "If it works do not output anything".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
keytool ... > /tmp/keytmp 2>&1 || cat /tmp/keytmp
```

The moron at sun who made the keytool should be fired.  Most ackward tool ever.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, that's not a friendly behaviour on the part of keytool.

If the set of success messages is small, you can use grep to explicitly remove them, eg

```
keytool ... 2>&1 | grep -v '^Certificate was added to keystore$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a bug report on the software. There should be a `-q` or `--quiet` for these kind of scripts, if it is not, I'd call it an unwanted behavior.